# Error "Service Unavailable" while using conjure-up openstack

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, conjure-up

I am trying to setup an OpenStack test environment and wanted to use conjure-up to do it.

I set up the lxd bridge via lxd-init and then tried to run conjure-up openstack-

It started bootstrapping the System but after a few seconds it aborted with the following error:

"Error: Get https://10.114.157.1:8843/1.0: Service Unavailable"

I suppose it has something to do with the lxd subnet i created earlier, but I am not sure whats going wrong there.

Seeing as conjure-up seems to be pretty straight forward for anyone else, I found very little documentation or advice on the web regarding the correct Setup.

If anybody could explain above error or maybe tell me something about the correct way to use lxd-init I would be very grateful.

With kind regards,
Florian Seifer

UPDATE:

This is my conjure-up log for "conjure-up openstack"
conjure-up/openstack: [ERROR] conjure-up/openstack: ERROR invalid config: can't connect to the local LXD server: LXD refused connections; is LXD running?

Please configure LXD by running:

`$ newgrp lxd`

`$ lxd init`

```
conjure-up/openstack: [ERROR]
conjure-up/openstack: Showing dialog for exception: NoneType 
conjure-up/openstack: [ERROR] 
conjure-up/openstack: Showing dialog for exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py",
    line 55, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py",
    line 30, in _pre_deploy_exec app.current_model)['provider-type'] 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/conjureup/juju.py", 
    line 32, in _decorator login(force=True) 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/conjureup/juju.py", 
    line 103, in >login uuid = get_model(app.current_controller, app.current_model)['model-uuid'] 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/conjureup/juju.py", 
    line 554, in get_model models = get_models(controller)['models']
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/conjureup/juju.py", 
    line 588, in get_models "Unable to list models: {}".format(sh.stderr.decode('utf8'))) 
LookupError: Unable to list models: error: controller walrus not found
```

Comment: Can you provide your ~/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log?

Comment: Strangely enough there is no conjure-up directory in "/.cache" .....

Comment: what version of conjure-up are you using? make sure you're using the one from ppa:conjure-up/next as outlined on our website.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make sure you've run `sudo lxd init` and go through the steps to setup storage and an IPv4 network for LXD to use.

Additionally, you'll want to make sure that  you can talk to LXD as the user you plan on running conjure-up as. To test that simply run `lxc finger` as your user.

We have a package update coming out in the next week or so that improves this new user experience and pre-configuring LXD to be ready out of the box for conjure-up use.